# How to Create a dynamic Panorama View using Dictionaries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, panoramas

I have a list of objects. I need to group those objects by a certain properties and depending on the number of groups, create corresponding Pivot Items using an Item Tempelate.

I placed the groups in dictionaries and placed the dictionaries in a list then passed the list to the Panorama Items Source.

However, the binding is messed up.

Can anyone help how to correctly bind those dictionaries to the Panorama Items?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are binding `List<Dictionary<object,object>>` to the Pivot Control.

There will be some issues when binding with the Key or Value of Dictionary, So better Implement a equivalent class for Dictionary and then try it.

```
public class CustomDictionary
{
public string Key{get;set;}
public List<string> Value{get;set;}
}
```

And Now, Your binding source will have a structure of `List<CustomDictionary<string,List<string>>>`. Bind it and let me know if it doesnt work.